# Euler's Basel Problem Rigorous Proof

Tags: products

In Euler's proof he uses the formula:

$$\sin z = z \prod_{n \mathop = 1}^\infty \left({1 - \frac {z^2} {n^2 \pi^2}}\right)$$

and compares coefficients of the $z^3$ term in the Maclaurin series of Sine.

But I was wondering how I can justify (rigorously) that the infinite product can be expanded like

$$x - \left( \frac 1 {\pi^2} + \frac 1 {4 \pi^2} + \cdots \right)x^3 + ...$$

I understand how it works using Newton's identities but I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that it is an infinite product.

Comment: He didn't. That was Euler: a huge genius who didn't care much for for justifying many of his genius sparks, both because back in that time much of this was new and was far from being based and axiomatized as today, and also because he just didn't care.

Comment: Ok, he didnt, but I think the OP is wondering about a method to do so.

Comment: Yes, I know Euler didn't justify it. I am trying to make his proof rigorous!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you consider $$P_k= \prod_{n \mathop = 1}^{k} \left({1 - \frac {z^2} {n^2 \pi^2}}\right)$$ Now, develop as a Taylor series limited to second order $\big(P_k-P_{k-1}\big)$and get $$P_k-P_{k-1}=-\frac{z^2}{k^2 \pi ^2}+O\left(z^4\right)$$ So, the coefficient of $z^2$ is given by $$-\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}\frac{1}{i^2}=-\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{\pi^2}$$ and the limit, for an infinite value of $k$, of the above harmonic number is equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.